# Why isn't this small redirect working (javascript)?

Tags: javascript

```
function redir(){
setTimeout(window.location = '/SV/main/main.html', 10);
}
```

I dont know if the delay is in miliseconds or seconds, but I have tried BOTH. (by adding three zeros).

Problem is, the redirect is made right away, without any delay at all... why?

Thanks

BTW its called like this: `<body onload="redir();">`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to put your javascript statement between quotes :

```
function redir(){
    setTimeout("window.location = '/SV/main/main.html';", 10);
}
```

The delay is in milliseconds btw.

As said in the comments and other answers, it is much cleaner to use an anonymous function to do such things :

```
function redir() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.location = "/SV/main/main.html";
  }, 10); // 10 milliseconds
}
```

Comment: You can think of setTimeout as doing an eval() of the code you give it.

Comment: Avoid using eval() wherever possible. You can pass a function as the first argument.

Comment: I agree ;) ! Using an anonymous function is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Much cleaner way to write this:

```
function redir() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.location = "/SV/main/main.html";
  }, 10000); // fire after 10 seconds
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
setTimeout(function(){window.location = '/SV/main/main.html';}, 10);
```

10 is milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

*setTimeout* takes a function and a timeout interval.

```
function redir() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = '/SV/main/main.html';
    }, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `href` property of location, and wrap the code within a function.

```
window.setTimeout( function() { window.location.href = '/SV/main/main.html';} , 10 );
```